# Order By asp.net is not ordering

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

Why is my Linq not ordering by the MenuID?

```
Dim categories = Aggregate pgmAccess In rvdDB.PgmAccesses 
                 Where pgmAccess.OperatorID = RData.UserName.ToString.ToUpper 
                 Join menuDef In rvdDB.MenuDefs 
                 On menuDef.ProgramName Equals pgmAccess.Program 
                 Order By menuDef.MenuID 
                 Select menuDef.MenuDescription Distinct 
                 Into ToList()
```

Comment: @Smeegs I agree with you. At first is looks like a poor question, but actually is not. Now this have nothing to do with asp.net, is just a LINQ query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first order the records and then use Distinct operator, which breaks your ordering. If you want the ordered results you should first use distinct and only then order by.

Comment: OK but then my object doesn't exist anymore so how can i make that work?

Answer (score 1):

`Distinct` is fully allowed to break ordering (ie does not necessarily return results in the order they're passed in).

In other words, to have your data ordered by MenuID, you need to `Order By` *after* `Distinct`.

Comment: I get an error the the object doesn't exist when I do that

Comment: @PieterdeVries What exactly are you attempting to do? If there are two rows with the same MenuDescription, does it matter which one turns up in the result (ie is either ok as long as there's only one, or does it have to be the first in MenuID order?)

Comment: I have categories and they need to be ordered by the MenuID. I didn't create the table so it kind of weird but the categories will have sub categories in one row.